# how to call a function when the mask of a list with store disappears in sencha touch 2.2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am to create a view with a titlebar and a row of two buttons and a list.
When tapped on,each of the two buttons will make an ajax request to the server and update the list below.That is I will give each button a handler in which the store of the list will be fetched to have its proxy assigned with different params and then to call load() to refresh the list.

So my problem is : how to make the buttons and the list masked when the list is loading and unmasked when it finishes.

At first i wrap the buttons and the list with a  container and masks it when the list is loading,but i can not unmask it when the list finish loading.I tried to listen the refresh  event of the store,but not work.

Second,i tried to disable one button when the list is loading and enable it when the list finish loading.But i can not figure out how to make a call to enable the button when the mask of the list disappear.

How should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to add load event of store before you call load() method and in load event's call back function you can unmask..just like below code

```
store.on({
            load: {
                fn: function( store ) {

                //you can write code for unmask over here
                },
                scope: me,
                single: true
            }
        }); 
store.load();
```